# How to find a common variable in a term?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have multivariate polynomials, like: `P = (a + b)(cd + ce)(f)(gh)(ijkop + lmop + nop)`.

I call groups:

```
(a + b)
(cd + ce)
(f)
(gh)
(ijkop + lmop + nop)
```

I call terms:

```
a
b
cd
ce
f
gh
ijkop
lmop
nop
```

`a, b, c ...` are variables.

I have next tables to represent polynomials:

`Table 'groups'`:

| polynomial | group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |

`Table 'variables'`:

| polynomial | group | term | variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | a |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | b |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | c |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | d |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | c |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | e |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | f |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | g |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | h |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | i |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | j |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | k |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | o |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | p |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | l |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | m |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | o |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | p |
| 1 | 5 | 3 | n |
| 1 | 5 | 3 | o |
| 1 | 5 | 3 | p |

How to select common variables (variable include in all terms of a group) for a specific polynomial?

For the polynomial `1` the result is:

| variable |
| --- |
| c |
| f |
| g |
| h |
| c |
| o |
| p |

P.S. I use PostgreSQL 15.

Comment: Is there any significance to `c` being repeated in the expected output? It seems odd to me you'd want it duplicated if you're not returning other information.

Comment: @EdmCoff I agree with you. `c` should not be repeated.

Comment: It seems to be [relational division problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_(%C3%B7)), see [this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) (named Divided We Stand from Joe Celko, for a case the link is broken - I hope it will always be able to be googled) to learn more. (Ahmed's answer's principle is also mentioned there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select variable
from variables v1
where polynomial = 1
group by variable, group_
having count(*) =
(
  select count(distinct term)
  from variables v2
  where v2.group_ = v1.group_ and v2.polynomial = 1
  group by group_
)
order by group_
```

When the count of a variable within a group equals the count of the distinct term values within that group then the variable exists in each term of the group. (supposing no duplicate variables within the same group, term)

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/XD64FFCo)

Comment: How fast is it query on millions of groups? How can I help the query be fast? may be create some indexes.

Comment: Have you tried it on your real data? is it slow?

Comment: I am designing the system, and I have a little amount of test records now, but in the production my estimate is about 100 millions of groups by 1-5 terms with 1-3 variables. Would be nice to know constraints of my model.